# Mosquitto TLS sets auto payload size limit

Tags: ssl, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I've implemented an unsecured mosquitto broker which works fantastically to send large amount of data periodically (~200kb file once per minute) over port 1883.

Since i've implemented TLS, the broker seems to reject data >128kb automatically over port 8883 despite setting the `message_size_limit = 0`.

heres my mosquitto.conf:

```
listener 1883 localhost

listener 8883
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
```

And heres my script which is used to test the broker which works fine without TLS over 1883

```
client = mqtt.Client("test")
client.tls_set(certfile="./mqtt/cert.pem", keyfile="./mqtt/key.pem")
client.connect("example.com", 8883)

#publish file as zip
with open("./mqtt/20180319171000.gz", 'rb') as f:
    byte_array = f.read()
    m.update(byte_array)
    file_hash = m.hexdigest()
    payload_json = {'byte_array': byte_array, 'md5': file_hash}
    client.publish("topic", pickle.dumps(payload_json), 0)
time.sleep(1)
client.disconnect()
```

Is there a limit on the payload size with TLS or is something wrong with my setting/script?

Comment: Rather than data rate (kb per min) can we have the actual message size

Comment: @hardillb each file size >200kb, sent once every minute, updated the question

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I experienced the same issue with large messages (>500kb). My solution was to increase the keepalive on the client from (default) 60 to 300 sec.

This is probably related to timeout for TLS encrypton on large messages taking longer than keepalive.

*Edit*: Added python-code for connect:

```
client.connect(
    host="example.com",
    port=8883,
    keepalive=300)
```

*Update*:
I found this question looking for answers to a problem that looked similar to mine, that is MQTT publish failed for large (> 500kb) paylods when using MQTT TLS. As @hardillb indicates in his answer, OP is missing `client.loop_start()`. This does not fix my problem, however.

`keepalive` should have no impact, but that is just not the case. Increasing the value definetely fixes the problem. My theory is that the broker failes the connection on timeout because it tries to PING the client, but the client refuses to respond withion `keepalive` because it is busy trying to encrypt the message. This is just a theory, though.

I've created some test code to illustrate the problem. I also included a "last will" to check if the connection is lost without a proper disconnect(), and it seems to fit my theory. Using too small `keepalive` definetely activates the last will on the broker, indicating a "timeout".

Increasing the `keepalive` does not activate "last will" on the broker.

Here is my code I used to test different `keepalive` values and payload sizes.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt_client
import time
from datetime import datetime

password = 'somepassword'
user = 'someuser'
address = 'somebroker.no'
connected = False

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    global connected
    connected = True
    print("Connected!")

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
   global connected
   connected = False
   print("Disconnected!")

client = mqtt_client.Client()
client.username_pw_set(user, password)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.tls_set()

client.will_set(topic='tls_test/connected', payload='False', qos=0, retain=True)

client.connect(host=address, port=8883, keepalive=100)
client.loop_start()

while not connected:
    time.sleep(1)

topic = 'tls_test/abc'
payload = 'a'*1000000

start = time.time()
print('Start: {}'.format(datetime.fromtimestamp(start).strftime('%H:%M:%S')))

result = client.publish(topic='tls_test/connected', payload='True', qos=0, retain=True)
result = client.publish(topic=topic, payload=payload)

if result.rc != 0:
    print("MQTT Publish failed: {}".format(result.rc))
    exit()

client.loop_stop()
client.disconnect()

stop = time.time()
print('Stop:  {}, delta: {} sec'.format(datetime.fromtimestamp(stop).strftime('%H:%M:%S'), stop-start))
```

Usig the code above (`keepalive=100`), it sends 1000.000 bytes and `tls_test/connected` has the value `True` on the broker after finishing.
Data is transmitted successfully, The console output is:

```
python3 .\mqtt_tls.py
Connected!
Start: 10:51:16
Disconnected!
Stop:  10:53:01, delta: 105.57992386817932 sec
```

Reducing the keepalive (`keepalive=10`), transmission fails and `tls_test/connected` has the value `False` on the broker after finishing.
Data transmit fails, and the console output is:

```
python3 .\mqtt_tls.py
Connected!
Start: 11:08:23
Disconnected!
Disconnected!
Stop:  11:08:43, delta: 19.537118196487427 sec
```

Tailing `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log` on the broker gives the following error message:

```
1612346903: New client connected from x.x.x.x as xxx (c1, k10, u'someuser').
1612346930: Socket error on client xxx, disconnecting.
```

My conclusion is: `keepalive` *does* have an impact on large payloads when using TLS

Comment: Please see the other answer I've just posted, the keepalive value should have no impact on this. Also encryption should never take longer than 60 seconds.

Comment: I would like to add a longer comment, using sample code etc, but my rep. is too low. You are correct that OP is missing `client.loop_start()` in the code, but that was not the issue for me. I suppose you ment `loop_start()` and not `start_loop()`. I agree that `keepalive` should have no impact. However, icreasing the value
definetely fixes the problem. Theory: Broker failes the connection while trying to PING the client. Client refuses to respond withion `keepalive` because it is
busy trying to encrypt the message. I've tested this using "last will" which is activated on fail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the MQTT Client loop is not being run.

When the payload is larger than can fit in a single TCP packet the call to `client.publish()` needs to queue up the rest of the message and this is then broken up into multiple packets and sent via the client loop.

The correct response is not to increase the keepalive period. There are 2 ways to solve this with the python Paho library.

First you can use the Publish class instead of the Client class. This includes a one function that handles all background tasks required to ensure the whole message is delivered.

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

tls_opt = {
  'certfile':"./mqtt/cert.pem", 
  'keyfile':"./mqtt/key.pem"
}

with open("./mqtt/20180319171000.gz", 'rb') as f:
    byte_array = f.read()
    m.update(byte_array)
    file_hash = m.hexdigest()
    payload_json = {'byte_array': byte_array, 'md5': file_hash}
    publish.single("topic", payload=pickle.dumps(payload_json), qos=0, hostname="example.com", port=8883, tls=tls_opt)
```

Second is to start the network loop as follows:

```
client = mqtt.Client("test")
client.tls_set(certfile="./mqtt/cert.pem", keyfile="./mqtt/key.pem")
client.connect("example.com", 8883)
client.loop_start()

#publish file as zip
with open("./mqtt/20180319171000.gz", 'rb') as f:
    byte_array = f.read()
    m.update(byte_array)
    file_hash = m.hexdigest()
    payload_json = {'byte_array': byte_array, 'md5': file_hash}
    client.publish("topic", pickle.dumps(payload_json), 0)
time.sleep(1)
client.loop_stop()
client.disconnect()
```